# How to make a entire div a hyperlink

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a div which contains back-ground colour and other styles, inside there is some text that contains hyper link. How would I add a hyper link to entire div so that when a person clicks on a selected div then whatever is attached to the id get executed:

```
    <div class="className" style="background-color:green;" id="IDName" >
    <a href="#" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Your Text goes here </a>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically click the div, execute a function? Or click the div and navigate to a new url?

Comment: Usin the HTML5 doctype, you can wrap a div (or most block level elements) in anchors. Simplest way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to add a `display:block` on `a` tag. by default `a` is inline element so by giving a `display:block` it will behave as a block level element.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zodarimi/1/edit)**.

```
a{display:block;}
```

Comment: This works well, but I would just add height:100% to ensure it fills up the div vertically as well. http://jsbin.com/zodarimi/2/edit

Comment: To center the text horizontally, use `.className a { text-align:center}`

Comment: @NickR I tried doing .className a { text-align:center} but it dose not work. is there any way i can do it within code by including style="text-align:center" ?

Comment: As this question is very old now and accepted by OP but Still someone giving a down voting on my questions. MOderator there should be some system which can capture who is giving down voting. Right now its very  hard to trace who have given down voting...

Answer (score 3):

You can set onclick on the div

```
<div class="className" style="background-color:green;" id="IDName" onclick="location.href=#" >
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" > <div>  This is the div wrapped by an anchor. </div> </a>
```

Comment: This is not valid HTML, it may cause issues in older browsers. It would be better to mimic the div using `display: block` than to wrap a  block level `div` with an inline `a` tag.

Comment: I know what you mean, but it's actually valid HTML5, and will work "well enough" in older browsers.